# syndaemon freezes the mouse

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I'm trying to disable the mouse while typing under Ubunty 16.04.

my `xinput` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech Touchpad          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried this command:

```
syndaemon -i 0.2 -Kd
```

And this too

```
syndaemon -i 0.2 -KRd
```

But they both give the same result, at first they work like a charm but after a while the mouse freezes, I can still click on the touchpad and it works but I can't move it.
I tried a lot of answers here but it seems none of them work.